# Publishing WCF RIA Domain Services under IIS 7.0 and Silverlight 5.0

Tags: wcf, ria, silverlight-5.0, publishing, deploying

I have some simple questions regarding the publishing of WCF RIA domain services under IIS 7.0:

**1.)** Do I need a *.svc file to publish a WCF RIA domain service under IIS 7.0? **Yes/No?**

**2.)** If 1.) is yes, is there any way to generate this *.svc file automatically or do I have to do it on my own manually? **Automatically/Manually?**

**3.)** My domain services are simple classes in *.cs files. Do I need to configure them "Always Copy into publishing folder" OR do the domain services "live" in the build "Web.dll"? **Always Copy/Live in the Web.dll?**

My questions seem simple, but I am having a real hard time to get this working under IIS 7.0. Debugging and testing in the internal VS 2010 development server is no problem.

I never had a problem to publish a "normal" WCF Service, because there are plenty of good advises out there, but for WCF RIA Services it's a pain in the ass to me.

**Thanks in advance for your short answers. If you have any good link to a tutorial on publishing WCF RIA Services with Silverlight 5.0, pleaaase post it.** I am working on this for days now and have googled my brain to death. I really don't understand that this is so hard. I have found some links here on SO, but some of them are already not existing anymore, some of them seem be useless, because the WCF RIA Services changed over the time.

Thank you and I really appreciate any help.

**EDIT: I already can debug the WCF RIA Service code on IIS in VS 2010, but only if the service is called from a ASP.NET code behind file. That tells me, that the WCF RIA services are working and running on IIS. This question is all about publishing the services to outer world.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to publish the project from the visual studio ?

I found some interesting links to read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912(v=vs.91).aspx

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/12/10/tips-to-deploy-ria-services-troubleshoot.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/wcf/thread/84b377b2-45d1-44d3-ba1a-7d9ef5ee939a

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: I have published the project with VS 2010 in the first place, but because of debugging issues, I wrote my own batch script, which builds and copies the files to IIS. I already know the first two links and the third is new to me. I would really appreciate, if someone would answer my simple questions in short. I should say, that I can debug the WCF RIA Service code on IIS, if it called from a ASP.NET code behind file. That works. But this whole "publishing-endpoint" thing is hard to me.

Comment: For all of you, who have the same problem deploying WCF RIA Services on IIS, here are two essential tips: 1.) Set Local Copy = True to all your referenced DLLs. They are then copied to the bin Folder. 2.) WCF RIA Services DO NEED a *.svc file. The svc file can live in ClientBin Folder and has to have the FULL Service Name including Namespace. And also very important: The correct Service Factory. A svc could look like this: <%@ServiceHost language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Fullnamespace.Servicename" Factory="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory"%>

Comment: Regarding the WCF RIA Service File. You can choose any name and path for it, but you have to take care of the service address, while invoking the service from silverlight (or any other client)